# Checking How Many Values in an Array are Greater than x

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Having created an array of values using a MySQL query, I need to check if they are all at least equal to a given value. This is for checking room availability in a hotel.

First I do the the MySQL query:

```
foreach( $datearray as $value ) {
$query_avail = "SELECT cupo, ex_cupo.room_id FROM ex_cupo JOIN ex_rooms ON ex_cupo.room_id=ex_rooms.room_id  AND ex_rooms.room_id = '$room_id' AND dt = '$value'";
$avail = mysql_query($query_avail, $MySQL_extranet) or die(mysql_error());
$row_avail = mysql_fetch_assoc($avail);
   $availresult[] = $row_avail['cupo'];
}
```

"Cupo" is the number of rooms available for a given date, so $availresult will be an array of the number of rooms available across a range of dates.

Now if someone wants to book (say) 2 rooms for those dates, I need to ensure that each value in the array is at least 2. For example, if there are 5 dates in the range and they are 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, I need to return false, but if they are 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 or 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, I need to return true.

How do I do that? (I hope I explained it well enough.)

Obviously the choice of 2 is just an example. It will normally be a variable called $numrooms.

Comment: This desperately needs some [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$testArray = array(2,2,2,2,1,2);

$valid = array_reduce(
    $testArray,
    function ($match, $value) {
        return $match && ($value >= 2);
    },
    TRUE
);
var_dump($valid);
```

How to pass $numrooms through:

```
$testArray = array(2,2,2,2,1,2);
$numrooms = 2;

$valid = array_reduce(
    $testArray,
    function ($match, $value) use ($numrooms) {
        return $match && ($value >= $numrooms);
    },
    TRUE
);
var_dump($valid);
```

Comment: This is looking promising, but I have hit a snag. I have created a test array
availresult = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => 2 [5] => 2 ).

When I have $value >= 2, $valid is false, which is what I want.
And when I have a $value >= 1, $valid is true, which is also good.

But when I have $value >= $numrooms and $numrooms = 2, $valid is true!!!!!

Comment: Thank you Mark. I still don't understand what's going on in there but it has worked perfectly in my little test file. I'm now going to press ahead with incorporating it into the real page. That is 38k of PHP code with numerous changes to be incorporated all the way through it, so it will take me a little while. However I'm pretty confident it's all going to work now.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `WHERE cupo > 2` to your SQL code.  Have the database give you only the results you want, rather than walking through the results to check that cupo>2 yourself.

If you need to be able to change it, use a parametrized query.  See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php for details.

Comment: At first I thought this was my solution, and so easy! However on testing it, a null value appears in the resulting array when the query produces a non-result. Thus the number of values in the array is the same whatever, which defeats the object of the exercise.

But thanks for taking the trouble to look at it and answer.

Answer (score 2):

you should pass the number of rooms to your sql statement as a condition 
such as:

```
$query_avail = "SELECT cupo, ex_cupo.room_id FROM ex_cupo
  JOIN ex_rooms ON   ex_cupo.room_id=ex_rooms.room_id  AND
    ex_rooms.room_id = '$room_id' AND dt = '$value' WHERE cupo > 1";
```

as the number one could be your PHP passed value.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do this at the SQL level (as Andy suggested), that would be the **best option**. However, if you need to do this in PHP, you could easily iterate over your array, and set a flag to false if any value is below your minimum amount allowed:

```
$minimum_val = 2;
$enough_rooms = true;
foreach($availresult as $item) {
  if ($item < $minimum_val) {
    $enough_rooms = false;
  }
}
```